# Not able to create user from Identity provider in user pool cognito in Ionic 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, federated-identity

I have implemented 'Login with Google' in android hybrid app with the federated identities which is working fine and I am receiving accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken.
But what I want is, when the user logged in with google, the new user should also get created in 'User Pool' which is not happening right now.

```
AWS.config.region = _region;
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
IdentityPoolId: _IdentityPoolId, // identity pool id here
  Logins: {
    // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is 
       in.
    // 'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_x7DyN3tQH':idToken,
        'accounts.google.com': _idToken // idToken received from google
       }
  });
```

Not able to find any document which clearly states the process.

Comment: What I am trying to do, is it even possible right now for the hybrid apps ?

Comment: I am able to achieve this in web app using the cognito hosted UI, but I don't want to show that UI in mobile app.

Comment: Did you get it working?